# Did the Sahabah and the Tabi‘un permit masturbation?

Tags: masturbation, sahaba

many of the Islamic scholars say that masturbation is haraam( Forbidden ), but. Abdullah ibn Umar and some others said that masturbation isn't haraam and there's no harm in it ?

Please Somebody answer it I can't marry because I'm a teenager and the sexual urge is overwhelming me ? Please Help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islam_and_masturbation#Sahabah_view

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The noble Sahabah had too much Taqwa (fear of God) to be lying against Allah's (ﷻ) religion.

But the same cannot be said for random unknown Wikipedia writers. For example, they say the statement of ibn Abbas doesn't forbid it but in that statement Ibn Abbas is only saying that masturbation compared to fornication is "better" i.e, **the lesser of two evils**. Many scholars have this view; they say masturbation is haram but better to fall into than Zina. -- Nowhere in that statement did he outright say it was good/halal.

Furthermore, something just being written in a book and attributed to the Sahabah doesn't mean it was actually spoken by them. I would check the authenticity of the other statements before taking them on as real quotes. (*And were they to be real, read them in context because they could be saying these things in the same context as above, ie compared to Zina*).

As for your personal issue,  Prophet Muhammad (ﷺ) said [fasting diminishes sexual urges](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/30/15). Try fasting before resorting to masturbation. And if you really fear Zina, then do whatever you need to in order to avoid Zina.